# How to turn of Server Signature on IIS server?

Tags: iis

Currently I am facing a security issue related to Website [Sniper Corporation](http://www.snipercorporation.com) 
to turn of Server Signature due to which my Server Technology is visible.

Comment: Turning it off won't give much more security as server type can be detected in many other ways. Please seriously hire a security consultant instead of relying on broken pieces of knowledge you collected from the Internet.